# Check a Website is Responsive or not using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design

I want to check whether a website is responsive or not by analysing its HTML code. A similar question has been already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937745/programmatically-checking-whether-a-website-is-responsive-or-not. It only check for the tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

But if you check the source code of **websites like google.com, facebook.com, stackoverflow.com etc, they don't have this "viewport" tag**. But they are responsive too. They are changing the HTML code based on the user agents. For example, if google sees the user agent is an iPhone, it gives a different HTML code that is responsive.

So how I can check if these types of websites are responsive or not?

Comment: ... Uhh, request the page with different user agent strings maybe?

Comment: ok. Then I'll set user agent as iPhone. But still no way to check whether it is responsive. The code doesn't have meta viewport tag

Comment: Presumably if the code is responsive this way, it would be substantially different? Diffing the HTML, or perhaps just the CSS, of the two should tell you. Alternately, I suppose you could use a headless browser, and check for scroll bars (probably too much for PHP to manage).

Comment: You'll notice the question you linked to was closed as being off-topic.  Not sure why you thought asking the question again would get different results.

Comment: @cimmanon it was closed and the answer is not 100% correct for all websites. Both the questions are not so same

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yes. We have to find if the web page's width go beyond device width. As you said, I don't think PHP can do that

Comment: @GijoVarghese I don't know how you think your question is any different than the one you linked to.  It's unfortunate that the other question got an answer before it was closed, just like it is unfortunate that this answer got a question before it was closed.  Having an answer doesn't make it on-topic.  Off-topic questions are not allowed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alexander O'Mara for the suggestion. It's little trick. Not 100% correct way. But working for all sites.

```
<?php
    ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9');
    $html = file_get_contents("http://php.net/");

    ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7');
    $html2 = file_get_contents("http://php.net/");

    similar_text(substr($html,0,1000),substr($html2,0,1000), $similariy);
    echo $similariy."<br>";


if($similariy<50)
        echo "It's responsive";
else
        echo "not responsive";
?>
```

basically, what it do is compare the HTML code as computer and mobile. Then find the similarity. If the similarity is low, that means they are changing code based on user agents. Of course, that should be done for responsive sites

Comment: btw. You didn't find this solution yourself, you turned what Alexander O'Mara told you in comments into a block of code.

Comment: @Shomz ok, i have added his credits. But that not a big deal. I know that even before he said that. It's clear in my question